# XCode Compiling

Tags: c++, xcode

When I compile my XCode Code I get this at the bottom...Im not sure whats wrong?...I am coding in C++

> GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version
>   gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC
>   2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc. GDB is free software,
>   covered by the GNU General Public
>   License, and you are welcome to change
>   it and/or distribute copies of it
>   under certain conditions. Type "show
>   copying" to see the conditions. There
>   is absolutely no warranty for GDB. 
>   Type "show warranty" for details. This
>   GDB was configured as
>   "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   [Switching to process 2627 thread 0x0]
>   (gdb)

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    double num1;
    num1 = pow (2.0,4.0);
    cout << num1 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that?  It all looks fine.  I don't think `pause` is a command on most Macs, though.

Comment: @Carl Indeed, OS X does not have `pause` command.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess:

```
 system("pause");
```

causes the problem, as OS X may not have a "pause" command.

Answer (score 1):

That is some logging generated by the debugger, nothing to worry about.

The debugger is a process you can use to monitor your application at run time, if you haven't done any code optimization during compilation you can even change your code while your app is running.

If you don't want the debugger you can turn it off by changing the scheme in xcode.

Also the "pause" command does not ship with os X by default, is it something you made?

Comment: Did you figure out your problem yet? You could try setting a breakpoint and going through your application line by line to figure out what is making it crash, it aren't that many lines so shouldn't take you more than 5 minutes :P